# How can i add a hr element of each 3 of my looping array..using Handlebarsjs?

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a array of elements, i am appending them all to my form element. all works fine. But i am not able to add a "hr" element to each of my 3rd label.. i tried this.

```
<script id="locale-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each this}}
                {{#if @index % 3 === 0 }}
                    <hr/>
        {{/if}}
        <label><input type="checkbox" /> {{name}} </label>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

But not works.. can any one suggest me the correct way please..?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First register helper like `showHr`

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("showHr", function(index_count,block) {

  if(parseInt(index_count)%3=== 0){
    return block.fn(this);}


});
```

Now In Template

```
{{#showHr @index}}
    <hr/>
{{/showHr}}
```

Or if you want you can write generic helper refer http://doginthehat.com.au/2012/02/comparison-block-helper-for-handlebars-templates/

## Edit for comment question

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("moduloIf", function(index_count,mod,block) {

  if(parseInt(index_count)%(mod)=== 0){
    return block.fn(this);}
});
```

Considering index start from 0

```
// If index is 0 open div
// if index is 3 means open a div
{{#moduloIf @index 0}}
 <div>
{{/moduloIf}}
{{#moduloIf @index 3}}
 <div>
{{/moduloIf}}

 {{name}}
 // if index+1 is  modulo 3 close div
 {{#moduloIf @index+1 3}}
 </div>
 {{/moduloIf}}
```

Comment: yes, this is working fine. but i unable to understand the steps.. of process

Comment: handlebar if is a inbuilt helper which accept only boolean may be null which considering false even if you proceed any operation it won't work.to do more conditional operation use block refer this helper.http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html if you don't understand let me know.

Comment: in case if i need to put each of this 3 lables in a div element.. where can i open the div and close as well... let me see this link.. now

Comment: open div near to label i didn't understand actually want as per my guess.

Comment: just i want to put each 3 of my element in to a div element.. exa: <div>1,2,3</div>,<div>4,5,6></div> like so..

Comment: Can u put another question so it's easy to answer me

Comment: It is really interesting. i am not an expert. still i need to learn more. definitely let me get back to you. now i understand a logic. thanks

Comment: @Amar, How can use the json data to the handlebars.js, which i fetched using the jquery get method..?

Comment: @3gwebtrain better ask another comment thread are increasing,may be  i will write some blog in a day regarding handlebar

Comment: hi amar, can you help me to answering this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648524/how-to-make-column-based-element-integration-using-handlebarsjs-template-conso

Comment: `{{#moduloIf @index 0}}` would do `index % 0 == 0`, which probably isn't right. You might need a third argument to get the "first and last" thing you're trying for here, or just write two helpers: one for the first item, one for the last item.